# Export csv file in browser

Tags: java, export-to-csv

I'm trying to export csv file from browser.
So the flow is next. When i on GUI click on button export it should create csv file in backend and show it to me in browser (as downloaded).
But that is not happend.
When i click on button it call my method from backend it create csv file and store it to folder but it doesn't show me that file in browser.

Here is my code:

```
public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {       
    try {
        // create FileWriter object with file as parameter 
        FileWriter outputfile = new FileWriter("exported.csv"); 

        // create CSVWriter object filewriter object as parameter 
        CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(outputfile); 

        // create a List which contains String array 
        List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>(); 
        data.add(new String[] { "Name", "Class", "Marks" }); 
        data.add(new String[] { "Aman", "10", "620" }); 
        data.add(new String[] { "Suraj", "10", "630" }); 
        writer.writeAll(data); 

        // closing writer connection 
        writer.close(); 
        response.setContentType("application/ms-excel"); // or you can use text/csv
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=exported.csv"); 
    } 
    catch (IOException e) { 
       e.printStackTrace(); 
    } 
}
```

EDIT:

angular part:

```
.service('ExportService', function($http) {
        this.export = function() {
            return $http.post('/data/export', { responseType: 'application/octet-stream' });
        };
    })

$scope.export = function() {
    ExportService.export()
        .success(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            var blob = new Blob([data], { type: 'application/octet-stream' });
            saveAs(blob, 'Exported  - exported.csv');
            $.growl({ message: '<br>successfully exported', title: '<b>SUCCESS</b>' }, { type: 'success' });
                })
        .error(function(data, status, headers, config) {
            $.growl({ message: '<br>Exporting failed', title: '<b>ERROR</b>' }, { type: 'danger' });
            });
    }
```

Does anyone know what could be the problem?

Comment: What makes you think that setting that header attribute  is sufficient to have the server do a full file transfer? Btw: what tooling are you using? Tomcat?

Comment: That's example of header that i've found on internet. Yes I'm using tomcat.

Comment: First of all, I suggest you try to find out where the problem is. Test your file download  by visiting the URL with the browser with your favourite REST-service client. I like Postman - but that's just my personal preference.

If you are able to download the file using Postman, then your issue is in your Angular code. In this case, try asking a new question and tag it accordingly.

If the file download does not work using Postman, there should be some kind or error, both in the response and in the server log. That's valuable information. Please add some details.

Comment: @JochenReinhardt I've forgot one js and because of that it didn't download file. But now the problem that file is empty. There are no data in file that i've send from backend

Comment: Have you applied the fixes proposed by @stevecross ? Your original server-side implementation would probably create an empty file.

Answer (score 2):

You never send the file to the client. You don't even have to write the data to a file on your server first. Just use an `OutputStreamWriter`:

```
public void export(HttpServletResponse response) throws IOException {
    try (CSVWriter writer = new CSVWriter(new OutputStreamWriter(response.getOutputStream(), StandardCharsets.UTF_8)) {
        response.setContentType("text/csv");
        response.setHeader("Content-Disposition", "attachment; filename=exported.csv");

        List<String[]> data = new ArrayList<String[]>();

        data.add(new String[] { "Name", "Class", "Marks" });
        data.add(new String[] { "Aman", "10", "620" });
        data.add(new String[] { "Suraj", "10", "630" });

        writer.writeAll(data);
    }
}
```

By the way: I replaced the `try` block with a `try-with-resources` block. This way you make sure that the `close()` method of the writer is always called, even if there was an exception. Additionally there is no need to catch the exception at this place, as callers of the method must handle `IOException`s anyways.

Comment: I try this but still it doesn't send filde to the client and it does't show any error during execution.

Comment: I've added angular part, maybe there is some problem

Comment: Are you sure that the `export` method is called? Please show us the calling code. Did you try to download the file 'manually'? For example with curl.

Comment: yes i'm sure. i check with debugger and it call method. I've forgot one js and because of that it didn't download file. But now the problem that file is empty. There are no data in file that i've send from backend

Comment: I verified the code that I posted directly inside a servlet and it definitely works. But since you don't provide the code of the servlet that calls the `export` method, I can not help you further.

Answer (score 0):

You are writing your data to a file called `exported.csv` locally on the server. This file is not sent to the client.

You should instead write the file's content to the `response.getOutputStream()`.

Comment: I've tried but it didn't help. I've updated question with angular part